# In place construction of a pair of nonmovable, non copyable in a std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, containers, move-semantics

Assume a following non copyable and non movable struct `X` with no default constructor and with no single argument constructor:

```
struct X
{
    X(int x, int y) { }
    X(const X&) = delete;
    X(X&&) = delete;
};
```

and a vector `std::vector<pair<X,X>> v`. For inserting into `v` one could use `emplace_back` if `X` was constructible from just one argument, since it effectively calls the constructor of `std::pair<X,X>`.
We could do something like this:

```
v.emplace_back(X(42,42),X(69,69));
```

but in this case a move constructor of `X` gets called and the latter does not compile. Since this is not possible, we have to make use of the `std::piecewise_construct` constructor of std::pair and call:

```
v.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(42,42), std::forward_as_tuple(69,69));
```

I would expect this to work properly, but the vector, for some reason, is calling move ctor (or copy, if only move was deleted).

For example changing the container to be `std::list`, everything works just fine. Adding a `<` operator to `X` and creating a `std::map<X,X>` (which has pairs of X as the nodes) or `std::set<std::pair<X,X>>` and using `emplace` instead of `emplace_back` all seems to work. What is wrong with `std::vector`?

Full code snippet can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/955rMxG16).

Comment: Clang's error message is [relatively clear](https://godbolt.org/z/8KhG5vfzz): "The specified type does not meet the requirements of *Cpp17MoveInsertable*".

Comment: If vector size reaches its capacity then insert operation cause memory reallocation and moving all existing elements to the new continuous memory block.

Comment: Even if you `reserve` enough capacity so that no reallocation occurs, every insertion function will still fail to compile as those functions can't know that they won't need to move or copy any elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector` is subject to reallocation once the size reach the capacity.
when reallocating the elements into a new memory segment std::vector has to copy/move the values from the old segment and this is made by calling copy/move constructors.

if you don't need that the elements are sequential in memory you can use `std::deque` instead, since `std::deque` doesn't reallocate the elements internally.

you can't store non copyable and non moveable objects into `std::vector`s.

---

EDIT suggested by @François Andrieux

In case you still need for any reason an `std::vector` you may think to use a vector made using `std::unique_ptr<X>` as *value type* using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>>`.

With this solution you still don't get a sequential order in memory of your elements, and they are keep in memory till they are still in the vector, so except in case you are forced by any reason to use `std::vector`s, i think the best match is still the `std::deque`.

Comment: I would also suggest `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` as an alternative if they still want a `std::vector`.

Comment: yeah that is also an option, even if is really near to use a std::deque. std::deque also allocates instances into heap and keep them in memory till the instance is still into the deque so i guess the best match in this case (since even with your option the elements are not sequential in memory) is std::deque

Comment: the at (@) won't work to quote your profile sorry